# How to convert snapshot.val() to object in node js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a firebase-cloud-function.I am trying to parse data [here is the data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgqMu.png) to object(model/pojo) or Hashmap as I believe everything in JS is a map, So i have written this code

```
exports.checkAllBookings = functions.https.onRequest((request,response)=>{

    admin.database().ref(`/bookings`).once('value').then((snapshot)=>{
        return snapshot.val()
    }).then((bookingDetails)=>{


        var map = new HashMap()
        map = bookingDetails

        console.log(map.size)

        map.forEach(function(value,key){

            console.log(value)
        })
        // console.log(bookingDetails.keys)
        // bookingDetails.forEach(function(childSnap){

        //     var item = childSnap.val()
        //     console.log("item ::::: "+ item)
        // })
        response.send(map)
    })
})
```

& this is how it completely looks alike [complete pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zglIJ.png). I have install Hashmap depandency from here [Hashmap npm install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashmap). But after all this I am keep getting   [error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdxUC.png). So how can I parse that data to a bean or pojo or hashmap in node.js so that I can move further to complete my task?? thanks for any help

Comment: You don't need  special npm package to implement HashMap as JS objects are implicitly hashmaps

Comment: @AyushGupta that's ok. But even without that Map stuff in code it keeps giving me that error. So Basically I am not able to iterate over snapshot.val() if it's a MAP. Can you guide me how to convert that data to MAP or Data class(as I do in Java)??

Comment: why are you doing `map = bookingDetails`? and what is the result of `console.log(bookingDetails);`

Comment: console.log(bookingDetails) results the complete object of data Structure. But even if i tried to iterate over bookingDetails it gives me that mentioned error. so I have tried to convert bookingDetails to Map which not works anywhere

Comment: when people ask **what is the result of console.log(bookingDetails);**, they are asking you to post the result. Until you tell us, we don't know what data you're working with.

Comment: @AyushGupta i believe you haven't read my question's description. There is a link to pic to data, I am referring to. So please check that pic

Comment: in the js console? as a JS object/array?

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: nevermind, not commenting anymore

Comment: @JOt: I wrote some possible options below. But If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to determine what you're trying to do. But if you're simply trying to return the data to the called, this is the simplest approach:

```
exports.checkAllBookings = functions.https.onRequest((request,response)=>{
    admin.database().ref(`/bookings`).once('value').then((snapshot)=>{
        response.send(snapshot.val());
    })
})
```

If you're for example trying to filter the data before sending it back to the user, you can use the `Snapshot.forEach` method:

```
exports.checkAllBookings = functions.https.onRequest((request,response)=>{

    admin.database().ref(`/bookings`).once('value').then((snapshot)=>{
        result = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(bookingSnapshot) {
            var booking = bookingSnapshot.val();
            if (booking.someProperty === true) {
                result.push(booking);
            }
        });
        response.send(map)
    })
})
```

The `if (booking.someProperty === true)` condition here is whatever you want it to be. You could do a similar operation to add more information for each booking.

Comment: Actually I am trying to iterate over the snapshot, I have tried to convert the snapshot value to MAP so that i can iterate over every key-value pair,but with no success. It keeps giving me error in console

Comment: Snapshots unfortunately don't have a `map()` function, so you'll need to use `forEach()` as in my example.